# How does a web service server process a URL? (And some reflection about URL in WCF)

Tags: wcf, web-services

I am new to WCF. One of the ***uncomfortable*** thing that I encountered is to use an URL (endpoint) to represent a method (web service), and use HTTP to invoke it.

An endpoint is composed of **ABC** -  *Address, Binding, Contract* (i.e. interface). And it looks like this:

```
http://www.myserver.com/myservice.svc
```

I usually put URL like this in the web browser and expect some page comes back.

The URL above I sent to the server is merely one of the many strings I sent with HTTP GET method. How exactly does the web service server locate a proper method with that URL string? I think the server should just do the following steps:

1 - Do some trivial parsing against the URL string, then the server will know the Binding protocol and Address, (this is the **A** and **B** part of the aforementioned **ABC**).

2 - Then, the *service host process* check the config file (be it app.config or web.config) and locate the target *service type*.

3 - The *service host process* (be it a console application, WinForm application, or a IIS worker process) should already load the *service type* into its address space. With the service type info found in step 2, it could use reflection to invoke proper method. ( But I am not sure how does the client send "*which-method-of-the-service-type-I-want-to-invoke*" info to the server. After all, we could only locate the service type info through an endpoint ).

So, from the above perspective, the URL is just an identification symbol, just like URL is used as ***xmlns*** attribute value.

Is the above understanding right?

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you service is hosted in http://www.myserver.com/myservice and the method name is "TestMethod".

when you call the test method this will the HTTP trace

a. assuming the method is POST

```
POST /myservice/[Service1.svc]/TestMethod
host: myserver.com
```

and will have a request body with input parameters for the method (sample : propertyid=357352&cultureCode=ENU&isEnlargeMode=true)

b. assuming the method is GET

```
GET /myservice/[Service1.svc]/TestMethod
host: myserver.com
```

there will not be any request body here.

Now, when the request reaches the server, the server identifies the method name from the request and takes the parameters from request body in case it is a POST.

Answer (score 1):

I don't completely understand what's bugging you here, but I would like to respond with a few thoughts/facts:

1. When using SOAP bindings (`basicHttpBinding`, `wsHttpBinding`), all you're "exposing" is the endpoint of the service; when hosting in IIS (which seems the case here) this would be a `*.svc` file that needs to exist somewhere in your IIS folder structures. That svc file then basically contains all the logic you're asking for, that describes what `ServiceHost` to create to handle the request etc., and the SOAP message contains the information about what method to call and what parameters to pass in.
2. When using REST (`webHttpBinding`), the basic premise and basic "way of functioning" of REST dictates that you expose everything as a resource that can be accessed using an URI - so it is the basic assumption of REST that you **do** expose your service "methods" - since those aren't methods, really, but resources you can work with

> *Do some trivial parsing against the
>   URL string, then the server will know
>   the Binding protocol and Address,
>   (this is the A and B part of the
>   aforementioned ABC).*

The **address** part of the ABC of WCF seems pretty clear: whatever you type in or whatever your client uses as the target URL is the address of the service you're calling to.

The **binding** is also pretty much a given since you have to prefix your URI with a protocol moniker - http, net.tcp, net.msmq and so forth

This leaves the **contract** which is defined by the *.svc file when hosting in IIS - the svc file defines what `ServiceHostFactory` to use to create a `ServiceHost` to handle the request; I don't really see how else you want to have this happen, and to me, an svc file is almost a bit like a config file anyway.

So what exactly are you expecting from "trivial parsing" in terms of figuring out the ABC of WCF ?? Can you explain a bit more? Maybe show a hypothetical sample?